# Create vector-valued function with arbitrary components

Tags: matlab, function, vector

Good evening everyone,

I want to create a function

```
f(x) = [f1(x), f2(x), ... , fn(x)]
```

in MatLab, with an arbitrary form and number for the fi. In my current case they are meant to be basis elements for a finite-dimensional function space, so for example a number of multi variable polynomials. I want to able to be able to set form (e.g. hermite/lagrange polynomials, ...) and number via arguments in some sort of "function creating" function, so I would like to solve this for arbitrary functions fi.
Assume for now that the `fi` are *fi:R^d -> R*, so vector input to scalar output. This means the result from `f` should be a n-dim vector containing the output of all n functions. The number of functions n could be fairly large, as there is permutation involved. I also need to evaluate the resulting function very often, so I hope to do it as efficiently as possible.

---

Currently I see two ways to do this:

1. Create a cell with each fi using a loop, using something like
   `funcell{i}=matlabFunction(createpoly(degree, x),'vars',{x})`
   and one of the functions from the symbolic toolbox and a symbolic x (vector). It is then possible to create the desired function with cellfun, e.g.
   `f=@(x) cellfun(@(v) v(x), funcell)`
   This is relatively short, easy and what can be found when doing searches. It even allows extension to vector output using `'UniformOutput',false` and `cell2mat`. On the downside it is very inefficient, first during creation because of matlabFunction and then during evaluation because of cellfun.
2. The other idea I had is to create a string and use `eval`. One way to do this would be
   `stringcell{i}=[char(createpoly(degree, x)),';']`
   and then use `strjoin`. In theory this should yield an efficient function. There are two problems however. The first is the use of `eval` (mostly on principle), the second is inserting the correct arguments. The symbolic toolbox does not allow symbols of the form *x(i)*, so the resulting string will not contain them either. The only remedy I have so far is some sort of string replacement on the *xi* that are allowed, but this is also far from elegant.

---

So I do have ways to do what I need right now, but I would appreciate any ideas for a better solution.

Comment: Is this a correct interpretation of what you're trying to do? You have `n` polynomials of degree `k`  in a single variable.  For some scalar double `d`, you would like a function `my_f(d)` which returns a vector of double equal to `[f1(d); ...; fn(d)]` where `fi(d)` denotes the `ith` polynomial evaluated at the double `d`?

Comment: Or is it: You have `n` matlab functions `f1(x)` through `fn(x)`, each of which take in a vector `x` of doubles and returns a single double. You would like a function returning a vector of doubles whose value = `[f1(x); f2(x); ...; fn(x)]`?

Comment: Or is it: You have `n` symbolic functions of class `symfun` in variables `f1` through `fn`. You would like to create a symbolic function `fvec` equal to `[f1; ...; fn]` for any positive integer n? Or possibly a vector of doubles equal to `[f1(x); ...; fn(x)]`, that is, the symbolic functions evaluated at a double vector `x`? Basically I'm confused what you're exactly asking for.

Comment: It is the second interpretation. As stated I have a number (lets say n) of functions fi, that go from a d-dim vector to a scalar value and want a vector containing the output of all n functions. 
Also n is fairly large, there is permutation involved.

Comment: I completely agree with your not wanting to use `eval`. But anyway, you *can* tell `matlabFunction` to assume vector input. Or is that not what you referred to with your last two sentences in point 2?

Comment: For point 2 (creating a string) the problem is, that when creating symbolic functions they can not have the form _x(1)^2+x(2)^2_. This means directly creating something like  'eval(strjoin({{@(x)}  {x(1)^2+x(2)^2'}})) for use in `eval` is not possible. (Also this kind of code gives me slight shivers)
Or were you talking about point 1, since you mentioned matlabFunction.

Comment: It [*is* possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32803436/5067311) with `matlabFunction` to use input as `x(1)`, `x(2)` etc, but I'd also avoid it.

Comment: I think I am already doing what you mention. In option 1 I get functions containing symbolic x1,x2,... (from vector symbol x) which `matlabFunction` correctly translates to in(1), in(2),... for input vector _in_.

Comment: Ah, OK then. I just wanted to make sure you know about that option.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the problem, you could do the straightforward:

Initialization step:

```
my_fns = cell(n, 1);  %where n is number of functions
my_fns{1} = @f1;   % Assuming f1 is defined in f1.m etc...
my_fns{2} = @f2;
```

Evaluation at `x`:

```
z = zeros(n, 1);
for i=1:n,
   z(i) = my_fns{i}(x)
end
```

For example if you put it in `my_evaluate.m`:

```
function z = my_evaluate(my_fns, x)
  z = zeros(n, 1);
  for i=1:n,
    z(i) = my_fns{i}(x)
  end
```

#### How might this possibly be sped up?

Depends on if you have special structure than can be exploited.

- Are there calculations common to some subset of `f1` through `fn` that need not be repeated with each function call?   Eg. if the common calculation step is costly, you could do `y = f_helper(x)` and `z(i) = fi(x, y)`.
- Can the functions `f1...fn` be vector / matrix friendly, allowing evaluation of multiple points with each function call?

The *big issue* is how fast your function calls `f1` through `fn` are, not how you collect the results from those calls in a vector.

Comment: I disagree with your last comment: from what I understand, I think OP essentially wants a very general way of constructing functions from R^n to R^m. Using a single array-valued anonymous function vs an array of scalar anonymous functions would indeed show as a massive impact in runtime.

Comment: I think you propose to replace the `cellfun` with a loop, which I should have thought about sooner, as it is usually an improvement ( I remember  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284027/cellfun-versus-simple-matlab-loop-performance .
But I as Andras mentioned, I believe further speed up could be possible. 
If I type a number of functions into a single array by hand, I think it should be faster than putting them into a cell and running a loop.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Agreed that a single, vectorized function from R^n to R^m would almost certainly be faster than array of scalar functions. This brings up what I find so bizarre about the question: to optimize for speed, you need specifics. With the problem phrased in such a highly general way, there's really not much useful to say. The question in a sense is: "how do I write a fast function from R^m to R^n?" Well, it depends on what the function is!

Comment: I believe it's intentionally general: consider a GUI where you load some data and compute coefficients for a basis. And the basis can be constructed in many ways, from various special function/polynomial sets. I think OP is after something lke this, at least the question specification seems to tell me that.